# Enable location services in nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

How can I enable location services in nihtmare.js?
I need to use them for testing.

Comment: Could you me more precise, are you talking about `navigator.geolocation` or something else?

Comment: @MaksimLuzik I mean Location Services that are in Chrome browser that allow to get user coordinates.

Comment: Please provide at least a code or something that you have tried already. Have you actually tried if you run Nightmare.js with Chrome, that the `navigator.geolocation` isnt available?